# NavDeepLinkBuilder is not redirecting to the destination fragment

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-architecture-navigation

I am using multiple navigation graph with multiple activities, and trying to deep link to a specific navigation graph destination fragment but it is opening the launcher activity

```
 val args = Bundle()
args.putParcelable("parceable",parceableObject)
args.putString("type","type")

val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(applicationContext)
    .setGraph(R.navigation.bottom_nav_navigation)
    .setDestination(R.id.myFragment)
    .setArguments(args)
    .createPendingIntent()
```

This is how I am creating NavDeepLinkBuilder.

Following is the destination in the navigation graph look like

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/myFragment"
        android:name="com.view.brands.MyFragment"
        android:label="BrandOffersFragment"
        >

    <argument
            android:name="parceableObject"
            app:argType="com.view.brands.ParceableObject"
            />
    <argument
            android:name="type"
            app:argType="string"
            />
    <argument
            android:name="is_card"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            app:argType="boolean"/>
    <action
            android:id="@+id/action_myFragment_to_secondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/secondFragment"
            >
        <argument android:name="secondParceable"
                app:argType="com.view.brands.SecondParceable"/>
        <argument
                android:name="parceableObject"
                app:argType="com.view.brands.ParceableObject"
                />
        <argument
                android:name="type"
                app:argType="string"
                />
    </action>
    <action
            android:id="@+id/action__myFragment_to_thirdFragment"
            app:destination="@id/ThirdFragment"
            >
        <argument
                android:name="thirdParceable"
                app:argType="com.view.network.parceable.ThirdParceable"
                />
    </action>
    <action
            android:id="@+id/action_myFragment_to_thirdActivity"
            app:destination="@id/ThirdActivity"
            >
        <argument
                android:name="card"
                app:argType="com.network.apiinterface.Card"
                />
        <argument
                android:name="id"
                app:argType="string"
                />
    </action>
    </fragment>
```

Comment: is [this](https://medium.com/incwell-innovations/deeplink-and-navigation-in-android-architecture-component-part-3-b882ed5d5b32) helpful, if not then could you post some more information such as your NavGraph xml and code of R.id.myFragment ?

Comment: @NikhilSharma the post is not helpful, I have to send notification from FirebaseMessagingService with deep link, I have created an extension function for NotificationManager to send notification with deeplink pending intent as above. I have edit the code. please take a look if it can specify the problem

Comment: Do you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using correct argument for `com.view.brands.MyFragment`

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/myFragment"
        android:name="com.view.brands.MyFragment"
        android:label="BrandOffersFragment">

    <argument
            android:name="parceableObject"                  // issue start from here
            app:argType="com.view.brands.ParceableObject"/>
    <argument
            android:name="type"
            app:argType="string"/>
    <argument
            android:name="is_card"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            app:argType="boolean"/>
</fragment>
```

What you are passing while creating arg for MyFragment.

```
val args = Bundle()
args.putParcelable("parceable",parceableObject)   //must be "parceableObject"
.....
```

I will suggest you to use [safeArg](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#kotlin) to avoid these kind of mistake in future.

happy coding !

Comment: I also tried with MyFragmentNavArgs, but it still not working

Comment: have you tried `args.putParcelable("parceableObject",parceableObject) ` when creating arguments ?